# Electron fixed position to the right side of the screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm currently trying to implement the toolbar which is fixed to the right side of the screen. Initial state works fine. When I try to dynamically change the content width from the app, BrowserWindow is resized well, but there's a blink on the wrong location due to the delay between setPosition() and setSize().

To get a better idea about this:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to either set the position and width at once, change the anchor point from top-left corner to top-right, rerender when its all done or anything else that would prevent the app from blinking when changing BrowserWindow width when doing this?

The way I currently do expand:

- `setSize()` Change width from 75px to 475px
- `setPosition()`: Recalculate position because we want it to stick to the right border of the screen and expand content from right to left

I've already tried with setBounds but it results in the same delay between this 2 actions.